# Grails, Spock Unit Tests isDirty behaviour

Tags: grails, grails-orm, spock

Assume I mock a domain class called Person within a Spock Unit Test in Grails (2.4.5),

```
@Mock([Person])
class SomeUnitTestSpec extends Specification {

...

    void "a test on person"() {
        when:
        def person = new Person(name:"Freddy")                

        then:
           !person.isDirty("name")
        }
}
```

The above test fails; Why? I would assume that nothing has been persisted to the database! Is there a way to override this behaviour?

Comment: Why would you want to override that? The test does exactly what is should do. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am testing within a pre-existing codebase.  Under the hood, my unit test has to mock a domain class that contains custom validation.  The custom validator specifies that a persisted instance of that domain class already exist if the incoming value is dirty (not an ideal prerequisite in my opinion, but neither my choice nor something that I can change).  Since we're talking unit tests here, I can't persist an instance a priori so I need to convince grails that my new instance isn't dirty.  It's a bit of a catch 22!

Comment: You cannot change the code? Or the unit test? Or both? Also can you actually post your actual code and unit test? I get the feeling that they are much more complicated than your simple example. Also you CAN persist something a priori. You can do anything you want in a unit test with mocks.